# solution to search into files (in lamp)

Tags: php, lamp, file-search

i have site that the user upload files (PDF,WORD,POWER POINT ....)
and they want to have the ability to search word in the files,
how can i do it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to use modules/packages/classes in PHP which allow you to read such formats as .PDF, .DOC, .PPT. Then, parse through the document and create database entries for words that you encounter, along with other relevant information. Later, you can poll the database for search results.

Answer (score 2):

we use [mnogosearch](http://www.mnogosearch.org/) for what you are doing.